# Windows7 socket connect when source port is same as destination

Tags: sockets, windows-7

Is this a windows 7 BUG or known behaviour???

when you make application that continuously tries to connect to some PORT (where nobody is listening), for example port 5000...

windows assigns for every try source port for that socket connect.

after a while (in my test source port is circulating in range 1000-65535) ...windows gives you that same port, 5000!

in that situation your application connects to itself and talks like loopback-echo.

so application will have totally diferent behaviour in that 1 of ~64000 tries.

i made tests with win-netcat

```
$ nc 127.0.0.1 5000 (with source port =5000 too)
on windows 7        ... loopback echo!
on windows 7 server ... loopback echo!
on windows 8        ... not connected (which is good)
on windows XP       ... not connected (which is good)
(managing source port to be exact 5000 was with separate batch script that run many connections... until source port is near <5000)
```

is this a windows 7 BUG ? and if it is known to someone, what is the best way to avoid it in your program.

Comment: How are you determining that the socket is connected to itself? Connecting to a **remote** IP/Port should not establish a connection to a **local** IP/Port since the IPs are different, regardless of the ports.

Comment: @RemyLebeau local address... netstat -ano |find "5000" shows established 5000<->5000   ... and also netcat start to echooing back every typing.

Comment: Hi guys, could you please have a look to a question I have recently posted? Something weird happened in my machine like a loopback connection i.e. same address and same source and destination ports. Any help or comments will be appreciated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481482/boostasio-server-client-socket-access-permissions-and-ports-issue