# Boost::asio server/client socket, access permissions and ports issue

Tags: visual-c++, boost-asio, windows-7-x64

A new error arose with my server (boost::asio based) once I implemented reconnection on my client but I am not even sure if this is the cause. The scenario is like this:

1. I run Client.exe which can reconnect in case a server is not running. Client.exe creates several objects which connect independently to my server. So several connections to my servers are created from the same process.
2. Because I haven't run the server yet, every object try to reconnect every 3 seconds (some of them concurrently so not always at the same time).
3. The problem occurs **sometimes** when I start the server: I get the "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions" error.

Looking with TCPView I found that everything looks good and it works. The server listen on the port 7000. But when this problem arises I can see a weird thing with TCPView:

```
Client.exe  9016    TCP ME  7000    localhost   7000    ESTABLISHED
```

How is this possible while the server is **not** running? same port? I checked and there is no other process listening on this port! How can exists and ESTABLISHED connection on the 7000 port if there is nothing on the other side listening. Then, of course, the port is in use by the client and I get this error (not really sure why I get this error and not something like "port already in use".

Notes: I do not have antivirus, windows firewall is deactivated and not other process is using the port 7000. I only have a server which listen on port 7000 and a client connecting to the server. After several times stopping (cleanly) and starting the server this weird connection appears.

EDIT: server and client are running on the same machine

Comment: From the looks of your tcpview output, you have a connection from the TCP port 7000 to the TCP port 7000 on the same machine, which seems indeed strange. Are you sure you are not mixing somewhere in your code source and destination port? Also, can you provide the results of a `nestat -a -b -n`, or a screenshot of your tcpview? There might be several relevant lines.

Comment: I am going to check the ports, thank you. Just guessing but I was looking at the dynamic port range setting for outgoing connections and I found that, on the machine where I am testing the apps, Windows 7 Professional, this range starts on port 1025. Is it possible that if I start clients without the server running and then they start trying to connect, one of them could use port 7000 as an ephemeral source port. Later, at some point, if I start the server listening on port 7000 something strange could occur like using the same port (both source and destination) because is the same machine?

Comment: Yes it can happen that Windows uses the port 7000 as a source port if it isn't already in use, especially if you're opening several connections at once and repeatedly, every time a new port will be used. I think you're actually experiencing what is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949858/how-can-you-have-a-tcp-connection-back-to-the-same-port